# Entity framework conventions

Tags: entity-framework, naming-conventions, poco, conventions

I have just started to work with the Entity framework and have created my Repository and context class and interfaces and defined my POCO and I am now trying to understand how the conventions working but am having difficulties and thus far have been unable to do so.

I have the following 2 POCO classes:

**Gameweek**

```
public class Gameweek
{
    [Key][Required]
    public int GameweekID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Deadline { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int NumberFixtures { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Fixture> Fixtures { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Result> Results { get; set; }
}
```

**Fixture**

```
public class Fixture
{
    [Key][Required]
    public int FixtureID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int GameweekID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string HomeTeam { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string AwayTeam { get; set; }

    public virtual Result Result { get; set; }
}
```

**Result**

```
public class Result
{
    [Key][Required]
    public int FixtureID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int HomeGoals { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int AwayGoals { get; set; }
}
```

In my model a **Gameweek** could contain between 0-20 **fixtures**. Each fixture in the gameweek has one **result**.

Am I modelling this correctly with the classes and the following convetions:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove < PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        //Table relationships defined here
        modelBuilder.Entity<Gameweek>()
            .HasMany(g => g.Fixtures);                  

        modelBuilder.Entity<Fixture>()
            .HasOptional(f => f.Result);                    

    }
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you want to have a one-to-one relationship between `Fixture` and `Result` (a `Result` entity cannot be shared between multiple `Fixture`s), right? In this case your mapping is not 100% correct. You need:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Fixture>()
    .HasOptional(f => f.Result)
    .WithRequired();
```

If you don't add `WithRequired` EF conventions will assume a `WithMany`, i.e. a one-to-many instead of one-to-one relationship.

Speaking of conventions, you can actually remove `modelBuilder.Entity<Gameweek>().HasMany(g => g.Fixtures);`, *all* `[Required]` attributes and the `[Key]` attribute in `Gameweek`. Only the one-to-one mapping above and the `[Key]` attribute on `Result.FixtureID` is needed. Everything else will be mapped automatically based on conventions.

Comment: Hi Slauma, thank you for the reply. Are there no conventions then needed for the Gameweek Entity? How are the fixtures then linked with their corresponding gameweek?

Comment: @Jay: EF sees the `Gameweek.Fixtures` collection. From that it infers a one-to-many relationship by convention. Then it sees the `Fixture.GameweekID` property and assumes that this is the FK property of the relationship (by naming convention, I believe). Because it is a non-nullable `int` it then infers that the relationship is *required* and not optional.

Comment: Nice on Slauma thanks for the explanation I was over specifying everything I think thanks for the help :)